# Host ASP.NET Core on Linux with Nginx - Site Can't be reached on Lan

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, nginx

I am trying to access an ASP .net Core 3 Web API on a Linux (this case a raspberry pi).

The API runs perfectly in the localhost, either on my laptop or on the pi when accessing it locally. However, when I try to get it to get available on the plan following the [ASP DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-3.1), it doesn't work.

I get the following if I got the dotnet app running:

> "This site can’t be reached 192.168.1.50 refused to connect. Try:
>
> Checking the connection Checking the proxy and the firewall
>   ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" "

If the dotnet app is not running and I try to get to the Nginx server I get the following:

> 502 Bad Gateway

**NGINX Seems to be doing something as with the app running it forwards it me to the  correct port 5001**

My Program.cs:

```
 public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

My Startup.cs

```
  public class Startup
{

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
       var con = new ConnectionStrings();
       Configuration.Bind("ConnectionStrings", con);
       services.AddSingleton(con);
       services.AddControllers();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        });


        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

Dotnet from the Linux:

```
    dotnet Fan.dll 
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /home/pi/WebApp
```

Linux Nginx Status / Configuration:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same issue, on Ubuntu 18.04, did you find a solution?

Comment: Hi @Ziriax the problem was on the NGINX Configuration. Missing the root pointing to the right directory location.

Comment: Thanks for the update. In my case the problem suddenly resolved itself, I have no idea why exactly. The only thing I did is I use the IP address of the site itself, and that worked. When I then used the URL, it also worked. Maybe it had something to do with DNS, since I only added the A record a couple of hours before testing...